# Why do you need to include the "return" keyword in a recursive function?

Tags: php, recursion

I have the following function that implements division without the use of a modulus operator

```
function division($dividend, $divisor, $quotient){
    if($dividend<=$divisor){
        return $quotient;
    }else{
        $dividend-=$divisor;
        $quotient++;
        division($dividend, $divisor, $quotient);
    }
}

echo division(3, 2, 0);
```

I'm confused why I need to prepend the `return` keyword to the line `division($dividend, $divisor, $quotient)` if the function is going to iterate until the if statement evaluates to true and `return $quotient` evaluates.

Can someone explain why the `return` keyword is needed?

Comment: It's a recursive function, so you need to give the result back to the calling function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because once the quotient has been calculated, you might want to do something with it. In your case you are displaying it with the `echo` statement. Without the return call, you cannot know what the result of the function is.